# Getting state of a variable to be printed out

Tags: javascript, html, css

I currently have a button that when I press it a table appears below it. My first question that I can't figure out is that I cannot get a border although I specified border="10". I am using firefox. Next I cannot figure out how to when I am done with my table to be able to press the button and have the table be hidden. My third question is that this table is being written as a test to see the state of my variables and parameters in my jsp are what I think they are. In my third cell of my table where I have just docs I want the the current value on the page of getDocs(). If I put it in the getDocs() then it gives me the result on page load which would be null. But in my showDiv() method  when I run my debugger it shows the correct value of getDocs in the var docs = getDocs();. How do I get the docs value in  docs.

```
window.onload = function()
{
    document.getElementById("button").onclick = showDiv;
}

function showDiv()
{
    document.getElementById("hidden").style.display = "block";

    var docs = getDocs();
}



 <input type="button" id="button" value="Click to show states" onclick="showDiv()"/>

  <div id="hidden" style="display:none"> 
        <table border="10" style="width:300px">
        <tr>
          <td>Type</td>
          <td>Object</td>
         <td>value</td>
        </tr>
        </br>
        <tr>
          <td>Element 1</td>
          <td><%=docs%></td>
          <td>docs</td>
        </tr>
        </table> 
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the border issue, what happens if you put the border definition in the style declaration:

```
<table style="width:300px;border:1px solid black;">
```

For showing / hiding, a simple toggler can be put into the showDiv() call. Try:

```
function showDiv() {
    if (document.getElementById('hidden').style.display == 'block') {
        document.getElementById('hidden').style.display = 'none';
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('hidden').style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

Need more code examples and explanation to work on the Docs issue.

Comment: for example. I have a method function getDocs(){return docs). When I am running this code right now if I getDocs then I will be getting null since the values are received on pageLoad when everything is null. Say I select a doc. Now getDocs contains for exmaple dog. So now I want when I click on my button to get Dog in my table. without having to reload the page. Since I have the onclick="showDiv" what do I do in that to be able to get dog into my table

Answer (score 0):

1) border is a css style attribute, so apply it in the css file.

```
#foo (yourid)
{
    border: 10px;
}
```

2) you will have to create the button and create a onClick() function (JavaScript). This function will retrieve the table (possible by id) then change the display to none

```
var table = document.getElementById("foo);
table.style.display = none;
```

3) Not to sure about this one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I will answer to each question here, but here you go anyway : http://jsfiddle.net/bbtVH/8/

You just need this javascript, since you use the HTML attribute `onclick` on your button, no need to add a listener in `window.onload` :

```
function showDiv() {
    var table = document.getElementById("hidden");
    if (table.style.display !== "block"){
        table.style.display = "block";
        // Just get docs from JSP, if you want to get its value :
        // var docs = <%=docs%>;
    }
    else {
        table.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

This CSS will give you borders of 2px around your cells :

```
td{
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for your border :

```
<table border="10" style="width:300px border: 5px solid red; display:none">
```

to hide the table :

```
$("#hidden").fadeOut("slow");
```

or to see it :

```
$("#hidden").fadeIn("slow");
```

the get the values from docs:

```
 docs.val()
```

Comment: He didn't say he was using jquery